# Multiple Fetch Requests?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

I currently have a `UITableView` with 2 sections that uses a `NSFetchedResultsController`. I am trying to work out how I display different entities in the different sections. I have a `FOLDER` objects and then also `TAG` objects. I am wanting to display all of these in each section, i.e. Section 1 all `FOLDER`, Section 2 all `TAGS`.

The relationship goes:
`FOLDER (one to many)-> MOVIE (many to many)-> TAGS`

How do I achieve this? Am I needing 2 separate `tableView`'s or to use a single `tableView` with 2 different fetch requests? Please help!

EDIT: Fetch and tableView `cellForRowAt` code.

```
  private let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
   private let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
   private var fetchedRC: NSFetchedResultsController<Folder>!

   override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    refresh()
   }

   private func refresh() {
    do {
        let request = Folder.fetchRequest() as NSFetchRequest<Folder>
        request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name CONTAINS[cd] %@", query)
        let sort = NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Folder.name, ascending: true)
        request.sortDescriptors = [sort]
        do {
            fetchedRC = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: request, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
            fetchedRC.delegate = self
            try fetchedRC.performFetch()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }
   }

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "folderCell", for: indexPath) as! FolderTableViewCell
    let folder = fetchedRC.object(at: indexPath)
    cell.update(with: folder)
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    cell.layer.masksToBounds = true
    return cell
   }
```

Comment: is the repo open source?

Comment: @FaZeUnempl0yedd No, it's just a project.

Comment: I could have a look if it was open on gitlab.

Comment: @FaZeUnempl0yedd I wish I could haha. Do you have any ideas about the problem though?

Comment: Please paste some code regarding your TableViews delegates / datasources

Comment: @Olympiloutre I added some code above. Is that the code you wanted? If not, just ask!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use 2 FRC for your 2 sections.

One gets fed by your folder fetchrequest and the other by the tags, all in one tableview. Your tableview delegate methods take care of what you want to access. This is quite easy to handle that way. It only gets more complicated if you have more than just 2 sections.
That way your tableview delegate knows by section == 0 or 1 which FRC to access.